# What is the best approach for storing two list of same type in mongoDB?

Tags: database, mongodb, database-design

I'm wondering in terms of database design what is the best approach between storing reference id, or embedded document even if it's means that multiple document can appears more than once.

Let's say I have that kind of model for the moment :

Collection User :

```
{
    name: String,  
    types : List<Type> 
    sharedTypes: List<Type>
}
```

If I use the embedded model and don't use another collection it may result in duplicate object Type. For example, user A create Type aa and user B create Type bb. When they share each other they type it will result in :

```
{
    name: UserA,  
    types : [{name: aa}]
    sharedTypes: [{name:bb}]
},
{
    name: UserB,  
    types : [{name: bb}] 
    sharedTypes: [{name:aa}]
}
```

Which results in duplication, so I guess it's pretty bad design. Should I use another approach like creating collection Type and store referenceId ?

Collection Type :

```
{
    id: String
    name: String
}
```

Which will still result in duplication but not one whole document, I guess it's better.

```
{
    name: UserA,  
    types : ["randomString1"]
    sharedTypes: ["randomString2"]
},
{
    name: UserA,  
    types : ["randomString2"] 
    sharedTypes: ["randomString1"]
}
```

And the last one approach and maybe the best is to store from the collection types like this.

Collection User :

```
{
   id: String
   name: String
}
```

Collection Type :

```
{
    id: String
    name: String,
    createdBy: String (id of user),
    sharedWith: List<String> (ids of user)
}
```

What is the best approach between this 3.
I'm doing query like, I got one group of user, so for each user, I want the type created and the type people shared with me.

Comment: Also, see this: [MongoDB Data Modeling](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/data-modeling/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Broadly, the decision to embed vs. use a reference ID comes down to this:

1. Do you need to easily preserve the referential integrity of the joined data at point in time, meaning you want to ensure that the state of the joined data is "permanently associated" with the parent data?   Then embedding is a good idea. This is also a good practice in the "insert only" design paradigm.  Very often other requirements like immutability, hashing/checksum, security, and archiving make the embedded approach easier to manage in the long run because version / createDate management is vastly simplified.
2. Do you need the fastest, most quick-hit scalability?  Then embed and ensure indexes are appropriately constructed.  An indexed lookup followed by the extraction of a rich shape with arbitrarily complex embedded data is a very high performance operation.
3. (Opposite) Do you want to ensure that updates to joined data are quickly and immediately reflected in a join with parents?   Then use a reference ID and the `$lookup` function to bring the data together.
4. Does the joined data grow essentially without bound, like transactions against an account?   This is likely better handled through a reference ID to a separate transaction collection and joined with `$lookup`.